# unoconv not showing image in pdf when converting from docx to pdf

Tags: phpword, unoconv

hi here is my code which is used to convert docx to pdf `$pythonPath = '/usr/bin/python';
$unoconvPath = '/usr/bin/unoconv';

```
    $command = sprintf(
        '"%s" "%s" -f pdf "%s" 2>&1',
        $pythonPath,
        $unoconvPath,
        $docx_file_path
    );


    
    exec($command, $output, $return);
    if (is_array($output) && !empty($output[0])) {
        throw new Exception(json_encode(implode('; ', $output), true));
    }
    return true;`
```

the image is visible when downloading docx using phpword with setImageValue function

```
$document = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord1\TemplateProcessor($docx_temp_file_path);`
   
                $value = '/www/wwwroot/vss/webrootimages//b6e176e4b84968f6cda8d28b17394bf2.png';
                $document->setImageValue($key, $value);
```

the image is not visible when i convert docx to pdf